# Let $D$ a division ring. Show that $Z(M_n(D)) \simeq Z(D)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $D$ a division ring. Show that $Z(M_n(D)) \simeq Z(D)$.

I'm having trouble mounting the isomorphism, do not know how to proceed.

Comment: The main point is to show the center is $\{d I_n, d \in D\}$). The iso is then not hard..

Comment: @quid:  isn't $Z(M_n(D)) = \{ zI_n, z \in Z(D) \}$?

Comment: Gave to resolve the issue with this hint. Thank You.

Comment: If you want to add in response'll accept it

Comment: @RobertLewis thanks. Yes, this is what I meant to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is to determine the center of the matrix-algebra. One can show that it is formed by $d I_n$ where $d$ is in the center of $D$. The isomorphism is then rather direct to establish.

(Reposted corrected comment as per OP's proposal.)